# Consulta para obtener datos de un trimestre

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Muy buenas,
tengo una consulta que se genera al hacer una selección por medio de un `<select>`.
En el `<select>` hay que escoger el mes y el año, y envía las variables a una consulta donde me extrae los datos de ese mes en concreto. ¡Funciona correctamente!

El problema es que quisiera hacer lo mismo pero obteniendo los datos de 1 trimestre. El año tiene 4 trimestres, entonces en mi `<select>` habrán 4 opciones: "1 Trimestre", "2 Trimestre", etc...

En el código compruebo el `$trim` para asignarle un rango de fechas para que luego me compruebe. Pero no me funciona.

Actualizo el código según las ayudas recibidas:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $trim=$_POST['trim'];
    $anno=$_POST['ano'];

      if ($trim == '1'){
          $FechaInicio = $anno."-01-01";
          $FechaFin = $anno."-04-01";
     } 
}

$sql_a=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM facturas,clientes 
                           WHERE facturas.id_cliente=clientes.id_cliente 
                           AND estado_factura=2 
                           AND facturas.fecha_factura BETWEEN '$FechaInicio' AND '$FechaFin'");
```

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mi duda sobre todo es ¿qué valor paso por el select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un trimestre son tres meses contenidos entre dos fechas (1 de enero de ese año hasta 1 de abril, por ejemplo).

Podrías utilizar el operador [Between](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) para seleccionar los datos posteriores a una fecha y anteriores a otra.

```
SELECT *
FROM facturas,clientes
WHERE facturas.id_cliente=clientes.id_cliente 
  AND estado_factura=2
  AND fecha_factura BETWEEN ('$fechaInicio' AND '$fechaFin')
ORDER BY facturas.fecha_factura ASC;
```

`$FechaInicio` y `$FechaFin` serían tus delimitadores de trimestre.

Comment: La consulta me genera un error en el editor SQL hablándome del LIMIT 0, 25. De todas maneras ¿Qué valor paso por el select? no logro solucionarlo.

Comment: Acabo de ver el código nuevo. Por el <select> puedes pasar el número de trimestre (1-4) y en el servidor, como estás haciendo, pones las fechas de inicio y fin. Respecto al error ¿Podrías detallarlo más? (Asegúrate de que las variables se están escribiendo en la query y no son undefined)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes preguntar si el mes se encuentra en el periodo que quieres. Ejemplo:

```
$trim1 = array(1,2,3);
$trimestre = implode(",", $trim1);

"SELECT * FROM facturas,clientes WHERE facturas.id_cliente=clientes.id_cliente AND estado_factura=2 AND MONTH(fecha_factura) IN ($trimestre) AND YEAR(fecha_factura) = '$anno' ORDER BY facturas.fecha_factura ASC"
```